# Documentation Generation is disabled

Tags: doxygen, sonarqube

I did all that is specified in the tutorial - [Doxygen Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Doxygen+Plugin). 
Here is the `sonarqube-4.5.1/conf/sonar.propeties` file doxygen entries:

```
# Doxygen
sonar.doxygen.generateDocumentation=enable
sonar.doxygen.deploymentPath=D:\Downloads\sonarqube-4.5.1\web
sonar.doxygen.deploymentUrl=http://localhost:9000/sonar/documentation
```

The output of the sonarqube runner:

```
16:07:16.265 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
16:07:16.266 DEBUG - Post-jobs : org.sonar.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenPostJob@28bda649
16:07:16.266 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenPostJob
16:07:16.271 INFO  - === SUPPRESS PREVIOUS GENERATION ===
16:07:16.395 INFO  - === DOXYGEN EXECUTION ===
16:07:16.396 INFO  - ### Generating configuration ###
16:07:16.427 INFO  - ### Generating documentation ###
```

Also, in the specified `\web` folder there is a `documentation` folder which seems to contain the correct doxygen documentation output.

Yet I keep getting this `Documentation Generation is disabled.` message in the SonarQube web interface:

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is what my `sonar-project.properties` file contains now ― using a unix-style path:

```
#Doxygen
sonar.doxygen.generateDocumentation=enable
sonar.doxygen.deploymentPath=/Downloads/sonarqube-4.5.1/web
sonar.doxygen.deploymentUrl=http://localhost:9000/sonar/documentation
```

The output remains the same, same issue.

**What do I need to do in order to see the documentation in the web server interface?**
This seems to be a *server linkage problem*, because the documentation is being generated correctly, at this location: `/Downloads/sonarqube-4.5.1/web/documentation`.

I have also found this content:

```
core,true,sonar-core-plugin-4.5.1.jar|9289fc1067c31372c0b020aa01163087
emailnotifications,true,sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.5.1.jar|bb35818e4a655a3ba2cff2afc65a296b
findbugs,false,sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.4.jar|bb0bf263ef1e0d56f569878732060cc9
java,false,sonar-java-plugin-2.4.jar|a105d018165ddeb2c0f5074100768660
cpd,true,sonar-cpd-plugin-4.5.1.jar|e11ff5066c9e2308036838510d87a6fe
dbcleaner,true,sonar-dbcleaner-plugin-4.5.1.jar|a444b3b4571791e1cde146ffa5132ee4
design,true,sonar-design-plugin-4.5.1.jar|0c6476994a44904307cfa8b8a08bbddd
doxygen,false,sonar-doxygen-plugin-0.1.jar|d86e1ab81c3ac34e6b31aa1da28d7f72
l10nen,true,sonar-l10n-en-plugin-4.5.1.jar|c21d53f67901cf6df3da1b4dd48a441b
```

in `sonarqube-4.5.1\web\deploy\plugins\index.txt`.
It looks like doxygen has a `false` associated with it. If I try to edit it (to `true`) and restart the server nothing changes. The file is overwritten at by the sonar-runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this:

1. Stopped the `sonar-qube` server.
2. Replaced the old `sonar-doxygen-plugin-0.1.jar`, from `/Downloads/sonarqube-4.5.1/extensions/plugins`, with the updated doxygen plugin from here `https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-doxygen/releases/download/1.0/sonar-doxygen-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.
3. Commented out the old configuration entries for doxygen from the project `sonar-project.properties` file. And replaced them with the follwoing entries:

   > ```
   > sonar.doxygen.url=http://localhost:8000/
   > sonar.doxygen.enable=true
   > ```
4. Used a simple [python script](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python) to post the documentation html on that server (`http://localhost:8000/`).
5. Restarted the `sonar-qube` server.
6. Run the `sonar-runner.bat` again.
7. The documentation is in its place now.

Comment: Is the sonar port 9000 localhost:9000/ and doxygen 8000 ?

Answer (score 2):

sonar.doxygen.generateDocumentation is a project property, not a server property. You have to set it in your "sonar-project.properties" file if you run your analysis with the SonarQube Runner or in your pom.xml file if you run the analysis with Maven.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the SonarQube server. Property `sonar.doxygen.generateDocumentation` is not even mandatory according to the documentation, and the server still asks for it to be set to `enable`, which it is.